# openCV: detecting a circle using findContours

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm working on a program where I should detect shapes of the same type, and color each type with different color.

I'm using `cv2.findCountours` and then `cv2.approxPolyDP` to detect each shape.

The program detects any shape with 8 edges as a circle, therfore I decided to add some examination - I'm checking the area of the current contour using `cv2.contourArea`, and I'm also checking the area of `cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)` of the current contour.

If they are equal, we have a circle.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, .03 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
    print len(approx)
    if len(approx)==3:
        print "triangle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(122,212,78),-1)
    elif len(approx)==4:
        print "square"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(94,234,255),-1)
    elif len(approx)==8:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        (cx, cy), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
        circleArea = radius * radius * np.pi
        print circleArea
        print area
        if circleArea == area:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (220, 152, 91), -1)


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I printed each of the areas and saw that the results are different - 
even when the shape is clearly a circle.

For example, for the same shape I got 628.254637106 for the minEnclosingCircle area, and 569 for the contourArea.
Another example: 2220.55512328 for the minEnclosingCircle area, and 2032.0 for the contourArea.

How can I calculate this area properly?

I will appreciate any help!

The image I used: 
[image]

and the shapes detected:
[image]

Comment: take a look to [blob detector](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) it can filter already by area, circularity, convexity and select properly a circle.

Comment: a blob detector will not be able to detect a circle filled with a different colour. It can only detect filled areas.

Comment: This assumption `len(approx)==8` for a circle is wrong. Since when did circles have 8 sides?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of comparing areas you should check convexity of counters

```
elif len(approx)==8:
        k=cv2.isContourConvex(approx)
        if k:
        #now you select a circle
```